# How to denote all unrepeated combinations of numbers in a set?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

In my homework assignment, there's a task:

> 2. Find set of all numbers which can divide 24.

Translation mine, I hope it's correct.

Through integer factorization I know that 24 is 2*2*2*3. Now I could just manually do all combinations of these four numbers and write them in a set:

$$\{2, 2*2, 2*2*2, 2*3, 2*3*2, \dots\}$$

That's a lot of work (or would be for bigger numbers), but maybe not the kind of work the homework expects me to do. Is there a way to denote a set of combinations of numbers? Basically:

*Let A be a set of numbers such that it contains all combinations of 2, 2, 2 and 3 without repetition.*

How to write that as math?

Comment: $A=\{a \in \{1,2,\ldots\}\,|\,a \text{ divides } 24\}$

Comment: Don't forget that both $1$ and $24$ divide $24 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3$

Comment: it isn't at all a lot of work, when we're dealing with divisors of $24$: The set of all divisors of $24$: $$\,\{1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24\}$$

Comment: @parsiad.  That's how to write the question, not the answer.

Comment: @fleablood Technically I guess I could write that as an answer I guess, but not with a straight face.

Comment: When I was in high school I went through a phase where I thought the funniest thing would be to answer questions like "Find set of all numbers which can divide 24" with "All positive integers that when divided into 24 leave a 0 remainder" and argue it is technically true.  The teachers didn't find it as funny as I did.

Comment: $$A=\{x\mid\left(x\mid 24\right)\}$$

Comment: @fleablood.  The mathematician Leo Morse was asked in an interview whether he could name a property common to only those numbers that are less than a million. He said yes. So he was asked to name one. He said,   "Being less than a million."

Comment: Well, as funny as that is... I kind of don't even understand the premise.  What did the interviewer expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean without repetition, you would just say all subsets of $\{2,3\}$.  Maybe you want to exclude the empty set.  That will not get you the list you are showing, because you show many cases with more than one $2$.  You could note that the factors of $24$ have zero to three factors of $2$ and zero or one factor of $3$.  Do you include $1$, which has no factors of either, and $24$, which is not a proper factor?  If so, you set can be written as $$\{2^a3^b\mid 0 \le a \le 3, 0 \le b \le 1\}$$

Comment: The number of characters in my simple answer in the comments above takes (2) fewer characters to write than yours, even when counting commas. :-)

Comment: @amWhy Yes, but I was looking for generic solution. I highly doubt the point of my homework was to write lists of numbers.

Comment: @TomášZato Do you see the smiley face at the end of my comment to Ross?  *Lighten up;* I was joking/teasing Ross.  My comment to you is that you is that sometimes a simple questions deserves a simple answer, and that sometimes, you need not take situations so seriously.  That said, I hope you noticed that I *did not* post my comment as an answer.

Comment: I didn't want to sound mean, just wanted to clarify why I even asked the question. Most classmates seem to agree that writing a list is OK solution, but that way I wouldn't learn anything new...

Comment: Actually, it depends on the class.  I feel from the wording of the question that a list of numbers is *exactly* what the homework expects.  However from an advanced mathematics/set notation/generic solution, Ross's solution is much more satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what level of class your homework is for but there are two possible answers.

1) is simply to list all the values:  {1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24}.  I don't think that can be considered too much work.

2) You list them as {$2,2*2,2*2*2,2*3,2*2*3,2*2*3$} [sic] which you note is tedious (although you actually had only one more to list).  When you say "Let A be a set of numbers such that it contains all combinations of 2, 2, 2 and 3 without repetition" you actually "Let A be a set of numbers whose prime factors are 2 and 3".

Use exponents.

{$2,2^2,2^3,2*3,2^2*3,2^3*3$} [sic].  To write this in math: $A =\{2^a*3^b|0\le a \le 3; 0 \le b \le 1\}$.  Notice that this includes both $1$ and $24$ as numbers that divide $24$ which you omitted.

Now to list these without repetition and worries of "where was I; what's next", simply list the powers of twos, from 1 to 8 first, then 3 times the powers of twos in order.

$A = \{1,2,4,8,$ *pause* $3,6,12,24\}$

So if you wanted to find all the factors of $1800=8*9*25=2^33^25^2$ for example you would list:

$A=\{1,2,4,8$  --> in other words that is $2^0$ to $2^3$

$,3,6,12,24$ *pause* $,9,18,36,72$ ---> in other words, that is $3*2^0$ to $3*2^3$ and then $3^2*2^0$ to $3^2*2^3$

$5,10,20,40,15,30,60,120,45,90,180,360$--> in other words, that is $5$ times everything done so so

$25,50,100,200,75,150,300,600,225,450,900,1800\}$ ---> in other words that is $5^2$ times everything done so far.

$= \{2^a*3^b*5^c|0 \le a \le 3; 0 \le b \le 2; 0 \le c \le 2\}$